# Text sliced into a path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path

[image]

I am looking to incorporate text into the path of an object, but remove that part of the path. I hope that makes sense.

So to put it more crudely, the result would would look like this:

> —————text—————

Except the line is the shape of the raindrop, and I just want a small portion of that object removed in favour of the text.

Comment: Please explain why setting text, then drawing two paths beside it isn't working.  There must be a bit more to the overall appearance or functionality you want than you've described.

Comment: Hi there, its not a line either side that i want, as explained above i have a raindrop shape object (stroke/outline only) already and i want to essentially 'cut out' a part of this object in favour of text. Does that make sense? I just dont have a clue how to go about it. thanks

Comment: Sorry. I'm not making sense of it. You want the raindrop to take on the shape of the text? You want text to overlap the raindrop but follow the same curve? You just want to remove the edge of the raindrop behind text? Some screenshots of what you've tried, and why it isn't working may help.

Comment: Ive just added a pic of the design itself. It's a raindrop shape. Instead of the text being above the path like the picture shows, i want it to be incorporated into (replace) the part of the path it overlaps. So as above it would look like this; -----text------

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not 100% clear on the end result you are after.

However you can move Type on a Path in two ways.....

Adjust the `Baseline Shift` on the **Character Panel**.

[image]

Or choose `Type > Type On a Path > Type on a Path Options` and set the `Align to Path` to **center**.

[image]

How you cover up or hide the path behind the type is another matter entirely, if that is indeed what you are trying to do. -- You could add a white stroke to your type on a path and move it behind the the `<characters>` item in the **Appearance Panel**.

If you *actually* want to *join* the type to the path under it, then you'll need to outline the text and cut/join anchors to make multiple paths into a single path.  Basically, there's no "two button click" solution to what you may be asking. You'll have to edit individual paths or the text to create the appearance you want.

Comment: I *believe* what the OP is going for is something like [this image](https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/14441/mystica-A-Heart-done-by-words-outline.png), but done for only part of the outline rather than the whole thing.